# RedirctToAction takes me to base controller of the present controller instead of directed controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers named as forms and mobile, In the forms controller I had a return statement calling a action in mobile controller like below:

```
public class formscontroller: customcontroller
{ 
public ActionResult submit(int? id = null, string jsString = null)
        {   code code    
if (CSConfigurationMgr.IsMobileUrl(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.PathFromURL()))
                    return RedirectToAction("home", "mobile", new { success = true });
  return code
}
}
```

home is an action

```
    public ActionResult home(string res)
            {
code code
}
```

But I am not able to hit that function, it is directly taking me to the base controller of forms, which is named as custom.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Check with Fiddler that you get correct 302 response, than see if you have correct route setup for that redirect location.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that "condition" never evaluates to true.

Please check that and ensure that the code execution gets to that point.

Might be more helpful if you post both controllers here (if they aren't too large).

Comment: i had checked with the breakpoint it is going in to the if block and then do as i mentioned in the issue....

Comment: is the if block evaluating to true? is the code getting to the return statement? might be more helpful to post more code.

Comment: yes getting true , going to return statement from there to action close brace and there after have to go mobile/home but going to  base controller.    mine is big code snippet , i hope probably the updated question may help to understand.....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a routing problem to me.

Maybe you haven't defined a route to your mobile/home/res controller and then the routing engine is redirecting you to your default one param route?

Comment: i dont think it will be a route problem as i had used the same controller action to build homepage , its worked fine so it should work for this case or else even if there is a chance of that issue please explain in detail......

Comment: routeConfig.MapRoute(
                "MobileForm",
                "{controller}/{action}/{*resxSetName}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "mobile",
                    action = "home"
                }
            );      if in case i had even tried adding a route even it didn't work .....plz have a look at the route above.....

Comment: Add your whole RegisterRoutes method to the question so us are able to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming home is the action on the mobile controller, then perhaps your signature is incorrect on the `home` action because it declares a `string` argument and you're sending a `boolean`.

Comment: string is the default parameter having default value set...and the success is enum...and my issue is going really weird so plz do have a look at the below link ....extend issue for this .......help me if u can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946370/redirecttoaction-not-working-in-a-particular-action-process