# RedirectToAction not working in a particular action (process)

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an Ajax call which will call an action called `submit` on form submission in a controller..

In that is something like below:

```
if (CSConfigurationMgr.IsMobileUrl(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.PathFromURL()))
    return RedirectToAction("home", "mobile", new { success = true});
```

It redirects to homepage and displays a "thank you" message.

I tried just giving url as `xxxxxxx/mobile/home?success=true` and it worked as expected.

I am getting true for that condition and going to return statement but i am not being redirected to the new page.

I've checked routes and found no problems there.

I checked by placing the `RedirectToAction` in another action, it worked fine, I am redirected to new page. But it is not working here.

Errors:

- `Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent`: Arises sometimes (mobile browsers)
- Nothing happens, just stays on the same page

Moreover, I tried to debug in firebug. After the call is made I get the process:

`www.test.com` is nothing but my localhost and its port number

`POST http://www.test.com/forms/submit` which is the right path to pass data

`GET http://www.test.com/mobile/home?success=true` the path I have to redirect to.  It keeps showing the loading sign, doesn't move further from there in firebug.

I suspect that the request is being made but not redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" means that you've already started returning the HTTP response to the client. Therefore you can't redirect it now. Look earlier in your controller method to see if it returns anything to the client and move the redirect check earlier.

The only other thing that looks odd is that you have the view before the controller (default is /{controller}/{view}), but perhaps your routes are set up that way.

Comment: ,even if return something to client above there are in some condition only one of all the returns will perform in any case, in this has to perform. But i didn't......r else can u explain me in detail please.......

Comment: @mandava - hard to say without seeing the rest of the HomeController function that handles mobile. Can you post the code?

Comment: what code do u want to see is it the action where we are redirecting or the action to which we are redirecting

Comment: even http error appears only i free play or debug few steps with breakpoints .....if i debug entire process till the end i cant see that error